# How to hide reference models in forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge, autodesk-model-derivative

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-containing-xref/task3-translate-source-file/ With using this tutorial I have translated reference linked model. Now I want to hide reference models in forge viewer, or want to show the only selected linked moldes not all. How can I implement this? I've read the blogs on Hiding element, where we can use dbId of the elements but here how I'm got getting the dbId of the linked models as well as levels.

I tried NOP_VIEWER.model.getDocumentNode().getAECdata(), from this I can see linked files but I find document Id and traverse Id of this. How can I get the dbId using this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the Model Derivative service does not carry this kind of information into the output SVF format, so the viewer won't be able to automatically tell which elements are referenced.

If this kind if functionality is critical for your use case, you could consider translating the designs individually, and then aggregate them in the viewer on demand. For example, in this [demo](https://aps-industrial-construction.autodesk.io/facility/montreal), instead of translating a single Navisworks file with many references, the referenced designs are translated separately, and you can load/unload them in the viewer during runtime using the checkboxes on the right side.